# Google FIT: Getting food item type (like banana, milk, Pasta, tea etc.) and meal type (like breakfast, lunch, snack and dinner)

Tags: rest, api, google-fit

Can we retrieve food item type (like banana, milk, Pasta, tea etc.) and meal type (like breakfast, lunch, snack and dinner) when the food item is consumed using Google Fit API?

The nutrition data is entered via MyFitnessPal.

As of now I can only retrieve nutrients data and total calories consumed using the Google Fit API.

Please direct me to some documentation or links or papers if this feature exists in Google Fit. I can see that in the documentation it states the types as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/Field) but not sure how to retrieve it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**I can see that in the documentation it states the types as mentioned here but not sure how to retrieve it.**

If you read the same doc link that you provided, you'll see that this fields can be accessed using [DataPoint.getValue(Field)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataPoint#getValue(com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Field)).

> This class contains constants representing the field names of common
> data types, each prefixed with FIELD_. These can be used to access and
> set the fields via DataPoint.getValue(Field).

Some code snippets of actually using it is found [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#data_types_for_instantaneous_readings):

```
DataSource nutritionSource = new DataSource.Builder()
        .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_NUTRITION)
        ...
        .build();

DataPoint banana = DataPoint.create(nutritionSource);
banana.setTimestamp(now.getMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
banana.getValue(Field.FIELD_FOOD_ITEM).setString("banana");
banana.getValue(Field.FIELD_MEAL_TYPE).setInt(Field.MEAL_TYPE_SNACK);
banana.getValue(Field.FIELD_NUTRIENTS).setKeyValue(Field.NUTRIENT_TOTAL_FAT, 0.4f);
banana.getValue(Field.FIELD_NUTRIENTS).setKeyValue(Field.NUTRIENT_SODIUM, 1f);
banana.getValue(Field.FIELD_NUTRIENTS).setKeyValue(Field.NUTRIENT_POTASSIUM, 422f);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is currently very cumbersome, since they don't provide a method to convert a `Value` to `HashMap<String, Float>`, which would be needed to get the nutrients field in a manageable way.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/Value

The API provides `asActivity`, `asFloat`, `asInt` and `asString` methods to convert a `Value`, but in case of a `Map`, unfortunately you can only ask for individual keys, using `getKeyValue`.

This is my current approach. I actually feel dirty about needing to go through a predefined list of keys and use `try-catch` statements, but an exception is what you get when you ask for inexistent keys in the Map.

```
    // Somewhere in your class definitions
    private static final String TAG = "NutritionHistory";
    private static final String[] NUTRIENTS_ARRAY = new String[] {
            Field.NUTRIENT_CALORIES,
            Field.NUTRIENT_TOTAL_FAT,
            Field.NUTRIENT_SATURATED_FAT,
            Field.NUTRIENT_UNSATURATED_FAT,
            Field.NUTRIENT_POLYUNSATURATED_FAT,
            Field.NUTRIENT_MONOUNSATURATED_FAT,
            Field.NUTRIENT_TRANS_FAT,
            Field.NUTRIENT_CHOLESTEROL,
            Field.NUTRIENT_SODIUM,
            Field.NUTRIENT_POTASSIUM,
            Field.NUTRIENT_TOTAL_CARBS,
            Field.NUTRIENT_DIETARY_FIBER,
            Field.NUTRIENT_SUGAR,
            Field.NUTRIENT_PROTEIN,
            Field.NUTRIENT_VITAMIN_A,
            Field.NUTRIENT_VITAMIN_C,
            Field.NUTRIENT_CALCIUM,
            Field.NUTRIENT_IRON
    };

    // Then for reading data
    public someMethodForReading(long startTime, long endTime) {

        DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_NUTRITION, DataType.AGGREGATE_NUTRITION_SUMMARY)
                .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();

        DataReadResult dataReadResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(googleFitManager.getGoogleApiClient(), readRequest)
                .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) {
            List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
            for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {

                // Getting individual datapoints (one for each date)
                for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                    Value nutrients = dp.getValue((Field.FIELD_NUTRIENTS));

                    Date date = new Date(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                    HashMap<String, Float> nutrients = getNutrientsAsMap(nutrients);
                    // Do something with your data
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }

    }

    // The method where the 'magic' happens
    private HashMap<String, Float> getNutrientsAsMap(Value nutrients) {
        HashMap<String, Float> nutrientsMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (String nutrientKey : NUTRIENTS_SET) {
            try {
                Float nutrientVal = nutrients.getKeyValue(nutrientKey);
                nutrientsMap.put(nutrientKey, nutrientVal);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        return nutrientsMap;
    }
```